# Menu item coming behind header of Datagrid Asp.net how to avoid it?

Tags: asp.net, css, datagrid

I am getting a very ugly phenomenon my menu item is coming behind the Header of the Datagrid in asp.net plus the Header of the datagrid is flickering on scrolling the Data

Any help would be appreciated

[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Give [**z-index**](http://www.w3schools.com/cssref/pr_pos_z-index.asp) in css higher for element you want to show in front of other. You also need to set the position absolute of the div you want to bring to front.

```
<div style="z-index: 8;">.......

<div style="z-index: 10; position:absolute">.......
```

Div with z-index: 10 will be show infront of div with z-index: 8

Comment: and also position to absolute.